# Join table to entry if within 30 seconds of Table

Tags: sql, join, time

Hopefully a quick one.

How do I join a table on a DateTime metric in SQL where I want the left table to be within 30 seconds of the right Table or equal to it?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some data?? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB on (a.Value = b.Value or a.Value = dateadd(second,30,b.Value))
```

Comment: depends on what is meant with "within 30 seconds" :). +- 30 seconds? +- 15 seconds?

Comment: Well in this case he can replace dateadd with `datediff(SECOND,a.Value,b.Value) =< 30` ;)